# Upload file to google drive using REST API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to google drive using rest API(insert) in node.js, I have access_token and refresh_token. how can I upload without any sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in testing this NodeJS upload by modifying the [NodeJS basic upload sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) a bit and mixing it with the already available [NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs)

Here's the upload function:

```
function uploadFile(auth){
  var drive = google.drive('v3');
  var fileMetadata = {
         'name': 'uploadImageTest.jpeg'
      };
  var media = {
          mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
          //PATH OF THE FILE FROM YOUR COMPUTER
          body: fs.createReadStream('/usr/local/google/home/rrenacia/Downloads/noogui.jpeg')
      };

      drive.files.create({
          auth: auth,
          resource: fileMetadata,
          media: media,
          fields: 'id'
      }, function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.error(err);
      } else {
          console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
      }
   });
}
```

You can use the NodeJS Quickstart as reference for authorization. Change `listFiles` function name:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
```

to the name of your upload function, in this case:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), uploadFile);
```

A sucessful upload on my Google drive:

[image]

Comment: How can i show list all file in web driver.google.com . I upload with service email, so main email not show file.

Comment: What is `fields: 'id'`, how to upload already exist folder at drive?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Node.js QuickStart for Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs)